# JSON Parse error on certain case - php

Tags: php, json

So I have a php code (_class.php)

```
class _class extends CORE {

//put your code here

public function __construct($mysql_setup = null) {
    parent::__construct($mysql_setup);

    if (isset($_POST["directory"])) {
        $this->updateDir($_POST["directory"]);
    }
}

/**
 * Populate files' infos from a directory into database
 * 
 * @param type $path
 * @return boolean
 */

public function updateDir($p) { 
    if (realpath($p) === false) {
        $this->output("Directory not found ($p) !", true);
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            $it = new FilesystemIterator(realpath($p), FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->output($ex->getMessage(), true);
            return false;
        }
    }

    $Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($p);
    $Directory->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        $com[]=$name;
    }

    foreach($com as $key => $path) {
        $filesize=mysql_real_escape_string(filesize($path));
        $lastaccess=mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',fileatime($path)));
        $lastmod =mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filemtime($path)));
        $itime =mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filectime($path)));
        $filetype =mysql_real_escape_string(filetype($path));
        $fileowner=mysql_real_escape_string(fileowner($path));
        $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
        if(!isset($path_parts['extension'])) {  
            $ext='directory';                
        } else {                
            $ext=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['extension']);
        }

        $dirname=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['dirname']);
        $basename=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['basename']);
        $filename=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['filename']);
        $inode=mysql_real_escape_string(fileinode($path));

        $path=mysql_real_escape_string($path);

        $queries = $this->dbQuery("insert into directory_listing(Path,  Filesize, Last_Access, Last_Modified, File_Type, Directory_Name, Basename, Filename, Extension,File_Inode, Inode_Changed_Time, File_Owner) values ('".$path."','".$filesize." bytes','".$lastaccess."','".$lastmod."','".$filetype."', '".$dirname."', '".$basename."','".$filename."','".$ext."', '".$inode."', '".$itime."','".$fileowner."')");       

    }        
}


/**
 * Retrieve all files' Informations in database
 * 
 * @return type
 */

public function getDir() {
    $queries = $this->dbQuery("select * from directory_listing");
    if ($queries !== false) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($queries as $query) {
            if (!isset($result[$query["Path"]])) {
                $result[$query["Path"]] = array();
            }
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Full Path'] = $query["Path"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Directory Name'] = $query["Directory_Name"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Basename'] = $query["Basename"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Filename'] = $query["Filename"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Extension/Format'] = $query["Extension"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['File Size'] = $query["Filesize"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['File Owner'] = $query["File_Owner"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['File Inode'] = $query["File_Inode"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Last Access'] = $query["Last_Access"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Last Modified'] = $query["Last_Modified"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Last Modified'] = $query["Inode_Changed_Time"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['File Type'] = $query["File_Type"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Note'] = $query["note"];
            $result[$query["Path"]]['Entry Created on'] = $query["Entry_Created_On"];
        }
        if (!empty($result)) {
            return $this->output($result);
        } else {
            return $this->output();
        }
    } else {
        return $this->output();
    }
}   
}
```

in my form.php

```
if (isset($_POST["mysql"])) {
     $class = new _class($_POST);
     if (!$class->isDbError()) {
     $class->getDir();
     }
} else {
     $class = new _class();
}
```

So the website will prompt user to input a path (e.g C:\testing), then system will call "updateDir()" to update DB (get the file info), and return to the site and display the inserted information.

The user can input blank path and the system will only display all data from DB (getDir())

Now, the problem is, when I enter the valid path, the system will do 'updateDir()' successfully, the DB is updated completely,,but when it wants to display to the front end, it echo out JSON.parse: unexpected end of data in firebug.

but, when the I refresh the page again, and enter nothing, the system can display all the information from DB without error.

WHERE is the place that I did wrong??

Thank you

EDIT:
my CORE.php is just a list of function that interact to the DB
e.g opening connection, insert, delete, and one of them is output():

```
 public function output($data = "", $error = false, $is_json = true) {
    if ($is_json) {
        if (!$error) {
            echo json_encode(array("result" => $data, "status" => true));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("result" => $data, "status" => false));
        }
    } else {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

this is my filesystem.js

```
(function($) {
var self = null;
$.filesystem = {
    url: null,
    directory: null,
    init: function(db_name, db_user, db_pass, db_table, directory) {
        self.directory = directory;
        self.mysql(self.url, function(result) {
            if (result) {
                for (var k in result) {
                    $("td.filename div ol").each(function() {
                        var li = $("<li>").text(k).data("infos", result[k]).click(function() {
                            var infos = $(this).data("infos");
                            $('li').removeClass('selected');
                                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                            $("td.fileinfos div ol").each(function() {
                                $(this).html("");
                                for (var t in infos) {
                                    $(this).append($("<li>").html(t + " &rarr; " + infos[t]));
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        $(this).append(li);
                    });
                }

            }self.start();
        }, db_name, db_user, db_pass, db_table);
    },
    start: function() {
        if ($.trim(self.directory) !== "") {
            if (self.url !== null) {
                self.dialog({
                    title: "Processing...",
                    content: "Please wait while the system getting all files' informations",
                    buttons: false
                });
                self.ajax({
                    url: self.url,
                    data: {
                        directory: self.directory
                    }
                }, function(result) {
                    for (var k in result) {
                        $("td.filename div ol").each(function() {
                            var li = $("<li>").text(k).data("infos", result[k]).click(function() {

                                var infos = $(this).data("infos");
                                $("td.fileinfos div ol").each(function() {
                                    $(this).html("");
                                    for (var t in infos) {
                                        $(this).append($("<li>").html(t + " &rarr; " + infos[t]));
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            $(this).append(li);
                        });
                    }
                    self.remove_dialog();
                });
            }
        } else 
            if (!self.is_dialog_open()) {
                self.dialog({
                    title: "Specify Directory",
                    content: $("<form>").append($("#template").children(".specify_directory").clone()),
                    width: 850,
                    height: 200,
                    error: true,
                    buttons: {
                        cancel: function(_alert) {
                            _alert.remove();
                        },
                        submit: function(_alert, dialog) {
                            self.directory = dialog.find("input[name='directory']").val();
                            if($.trim(self.directory) == "") {
                                alert("Please input something");
                                return false;
                            } else {
                            self.start();
                            _alert.remove();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

    }
};
self = $.extend($.filesystem, $.CORE);
})(jQuery);
```

and my CORE.JS is a script to pop up a table containing DB connection form (server, username, password) before proceeding to 'filesystem.js'

Comment: Your code doesn't output anything. You have to `echo` the result array, but before it need to be `json_encode`d.

Comment: what does the CORE class do? why are you passing the post array into its constructor?

Comment: Hi, in fact the 'return $this-ouput($result)' has been in json format...I have 'output()' function to do json_encode...
problem is, the getDir() only works if I input nothing (the path, so updateDir() isn't executed